# How to group numbers in x axis of jfreechart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I was wondering how to change the x axis so that instead of the individual point names they would be grouped up. e.g. this graph:
[image: share market price information]

I would like for it to look like this:
 [image: image container grouped x axis]

Comment: What have you tried?Please attach the code you tried and problem which you faced.

Comment: Use `setDateFormatOverride()`, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bjfreechart%5d%20setdateformatoverride).

Comment: I dont know where to start @Mandy8055 i'm brand new to jfreechart any resources that you have would be amazing!

Comment: Start with `org.jfree.chart.demo.TimeSeriesChartDemo1`, included in the distribution.